# How to right use Fast buttons in jquerymobile and phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

a need to speed up links with onClick attr in Phonegap app.

I would like to use Fast buttons plugin, that i found here:
https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons

But i dont know, how to right use this plugin should i add this after pageinit or where?

Maybe is it quite silly question, but if i tried to find some examples, with no luck.

Could You add somebody add put here some example, how solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `touchstart` (or `touchend`) event works great if you know the user won't be scrolling. That's actually the reason `click` events take so long to resolve on mobile devices, the device is waiting to see if the user is scrolling or clicking.

This will perform quite fast as there is no delay for dispatching this event:

```
$('#myButton').on('touchstart', function () {
    //run click code now
});
```

You can also use jQuery Mobile's `vclick` event which attempts to use the native touch events but it's main problem is that you can dispatch multiple events using `vclick` so you should set a timeout to only allow one click at a time, for example:

```
var clickOk = true;
$('#myButton').on('vclick', function () {
    if (clickOk === true) {
        clickOk = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            clickOk = true;
        }, 350);
        //run click code now
    }
    return false;
});
```

This will allow the event handler to run only once per 350ms which will take care of the multiple events being dispatched since the second event will be ignored.

I would set these event handlers up in a delegated event handler that runs when a pseudo-page gets initialized:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '.ui-page', function () {
    //bind "fast-click" event handlers now, use "$(this).find(...)" to only bind to elements of the current pseudo-page
});
```

Comment: But i cannot remake code to something like this:
$('#myButton').on('touchstart', function () {
    //run click code now
});

I calling functions from external js file directly by using onClick="myFunction";

Is any possibility for this?

Comment: If you are binding events, for instance with `onClick="myFunction"`, then just bind to `touchstart` or `touchend` rather than `click` (which is what `onclick` is doing). Also, since you are using jQuery you might as well take advantage of their event binding to make your life a bit easier. I think you're looking for this: `$('#myButton').on('touchstart', myFunction)`. Which will run the function called `myFunction` when the `#myButton` element is touched.

Comment: I thought, that is possible to use onClick in all a href elements and then override onClick fot tap, touchstart or something else. Using onClick directly in element looks better for maintance code.

Comment: That's a common pitfall, putting your JS in your HTML markup. If you place all your JS in one place, you will always know where to go to maintain it (you can also be more efficient about caching). In the end, whatever works for you is what you should do. I believe that `onClick` attributes are like `style` attributes, they override externally bound values.

Comment: I dont know that is  better dont use onClick in href, because if i have dynamical generated list with some params passed by for example onClick="myfunction('params1','params2')". How i can  to solve this situation if i should not use onClick in HTML document?

Comment: Save the parameters as `data-attributes` and then access them using `.data()` inside the function: `$('.my-elements').on('click', function () { var param1 = $(this).data('param1'); })`. So rather than using `onClick="myFunction(...)"` you would use `data-param1="..."` and setup your event handler "remotely."

Answer (score 0):

Jiri If it's not too late I had to do the same thing for my app and needed to pass parameters to the function. I did it by placing the parameters in the id of the button (separarted by underscores) and using this function which grabs the id from every clicked button with a classname of "clickbutton" and splits it into the individual parameters.

```
$('.clickbutton').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var parts = $(this).attr('id').split("_");
    var item = parts[0];
    var button = parts[1];
    var type = parts[2];
console.log(item+button+type);
    getItemCondition(item,type);
return false;
});
```

Still having issues with unresponsiveness from JQM click event though!

Answer (score 0):

What about [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) ?

FastClick is a simple, easy-to-use library for eliminating the 300ms delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on mobile browsers. The aim is to make your application feel less laggy and more responsive while avoiding any interference with your current logic.